# If $\Omega$ bounded, is it true that $f \in L^p(\Omega) \Rightarrow f \in L^{p+\epsilon}(\Omega)$ for small $\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$, and $f \in L^p(\Omega)$. Prove or disprove that there exits $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f \in L^{p+\epsilon}(\Omega)$.

It seems to me that there is no direct proof, but I can't find a counterexample. Any comments and ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p \in [1, \infty)$. Take $f(x) := 1 / (x \log^2 x)^{1/p}$ on $\Omega := (0, \theta)$, where $\theta \in (0, 1)$, e.g. $\theta = 1/2$. Then $$\int_\Omega |f(x)|^p dx = \int_\Omega \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{(\log x)^2} = \left. -\frac{1}{\log{x}} \right|_{x = 0}^{x = \theta} = -\frac{1}{\log \theta}$$ is finite. But $$\int_\Omega |f(x)|^{p + p \epsilon} dx = \int_\Omega \frac{1}{x^{1+\epsilon}} \frac{1}{\log^{2(1+\epsilon)} x} dx$$ does not exist for any $\epsilon > 0$.

PS. Of course, the term $\left. \frac{-1}{\log x}\right|_{x = 0}^{x = \theta}$ is to be understood with care. One [justifiable way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem) is to view it as 
$$
\left. \frac{-1}{\log x}\right|_{x = 0}^{x = \theta}
=
\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0}
\left. \frac{-1}{\log x}\right|_{x = \epsilon}^{x = \theta}
=
\frac{-1}{\log \theta}
+
\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} \frac{1}{\log \epsilon}
=
\frac{-1}{\log \theta}
,
$$
where $\frac{1}{\log \theta}$ is ok for $\theta \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: I think the question means that you can choose $\epsilon$ after $f$ is given. So in that case, if $f \in L^p$, then you can choose $\epsilon$ so that $f \in L^{p + \epsilon}$.

Comment: @user2566092: yes.

Comment: Your new example has a problem, the integrand cannot be evaluated at $0$ without blowing up, i.e. the function you propose is not in $L^p(\Omega)$ for the $\Omega = (0,\theta)$ you propose.

Comment: @user2566092: a function in $L^p$ need not be bounded

Comment: The integral of the absolute value is $\infty$ so it's not $L^P$.

Comment: @user2566092: cannot follow, please be more specific.

Comment: @user2566092 The integral of $\lvert f(x)\rvert^p$ is finite. This is a standard example of a function in $L^p$ but not in any $L^{p+\varepsilon}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, but this function $f$ in your example is not in $L^p(\Omega)$.

Comment: @QinfengLi It is in $L^p(\Omega)$.

Comment: @QinfengLi: I would like to understand why you think that $f$ is not in $L^p$

Comment: I mean $\int_\Omega \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{\log^2 x}= \infty$

Comment: @QinfengLi: cf [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28x+log%28x%29%5E2%29+from+0+to+0.5)

Comment: @Daniel Fischer,  $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{logx}=-(1/x)\frac{1}{log^2x}$, but $\frac{1}{logx}$ blows up.

Comment: @QinfengLi No, since $\lim\limits_{x\searrow 0} \log x = -\infty$, in fact $\lim\limits_{x\searrow 0} \frac{1}{\log x} = 0$. Note that $\theta < 1$, so there is also no problem at the upper end.

Comment: @user66081, sorry for my foolishness. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, thanks! I was stupid...

Comment: @QinfengLi Happens to everybody. More often than one likes.

Comment: @user66081: +1 The solution is correct, but somehow hard to swallow.  Why not write the upper and lower limit on the integral to clear the fog.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $\Omega= [0,1]$, and $f$  constant value $a_n>0$ on each interval $[\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}, \frac{1}{2^{n}}]$. You are interested in exponents $\theta$ so that

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a_n^{\theta}}{2^{n}} < \infty$$

To find an example of a sequence $(a_n)$ for which the set of exponents $\theta$ is the closed interval $[0,1]$ study a similar problem : find a sequence $b_n >0$ such that $\sum b_n^{\theta}$ converges precisely when $\theta\in [1, \infty)$.

$\bf{Added:}$ Take $b_n = \frac{1}{n (\log n)^2}\ \ $, you will get 
$$a_n = \frac{2^n}{n (\log n)^2}$$

Comment: @Qinfeng Li: No worries. It is a discretized version of the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0$ be a point of Lebesgue density $1$ of $\Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is bounded, the integral $$\int_\Omega \frac{1}{|x-x_0|^\alpha} \, dx$$ converges if and only if $\alpha < n$.  For each $k \ge 1$ define $\displaystyle \alpha_k = \frac{n}{p} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{k} \right)$ so that $\alpha_k p = n(1-1/k)$ and thus $$\int_\Omega \frac{1}{|x - x_0|^{\alpha_k p}} \, dx < \infty.$$ Set
$$A_k = \left( \int_\Omega \frac{1}{|x - x_0|^{\alpha_k p}} \, dx \right)^{1/p}.$$

Let $$ f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{A_k 2^k} \frac{1}{|x - x_0|^{\alpha_k}}.$$ Then $\|f\|_p \le 1$, but for any $\epsilon > 0$ you have  $$\int_\Omega |f(x)|^{p + \epsilon} \, dx \ge \int_\Omega \frac{1}{A_k 2^k} \frac{1}{|x - x_0|^{\alpha_k(p + \epsilon)}} \, dx = \infty$$ provided that $\alpha_k(p + \epsilon) \ge n$, which holds for all $k \ge \dfrac{p + \epsilon}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Thanks! Very beautiful argument!